# Javascript or jQ and DataTable(jQ) Trying to print by modifying table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

[image: Previous Table Form state]Javascript or jQ and DataTable(jQ) Trying to print by modifying table cell
But not getting as required. On replacement it leave header rows or duplicate header rows in input-form.
This is to print only table data and remove scrolling ,buttons  added by jQuery DataTable in print view. Printing is coming correct but restoring table form causing duplicate table head rows or duplicate table is generating. Top one in image showing generated by DataTable div element and table tag with its class attribute . i need to remove this item on restoring form table.

Please help.
Example :

```
<a onclick="printDiv(this)">Print</a>
<div id='idfortable' class="input-form">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="example1">
            <thead>
                <tr><th colspan="2">Data List</th></tr>
                <tr><th>SLNO</th><th>Input Form</th></tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><input type='text' value='1' class='some-class'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>2</td><td><input type='text' value='sdf' class='some-class'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>3</td><td><input type='text' value='gra' class='some-class'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>4</td><td><input type='text' value='sd' class='some-class'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>5</td><td><input type='text' value='rr' class='some-class'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>6</td><td><input type='text' value='ss' class='some-class'></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script class="removeinprint">
        var table_id= 'example1';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#' + table_id).DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip', 'iDisplayLength': -1,
                buttons: [
                    {text: 'Excel export', action: function (e, dt, node, config) {}},
                    {text: '<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-save-marks"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</a>', action: function (e, dt, node, config) {}}
                ], search: false, scrollX: true, scrollY: '550px', scrollCollapse: true, paging: false, "ordering": false,searching: false
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
<script> 
    function printDiv(js) { 
        var  tempdata = $('#idfortable').clone(); 
        var ddata = $('#idfortable').clone(); 
        ddata.find('.removeinprint').remove(); 
        ddata.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
            $(this).closest('td').html($(this).val());
        });  
        ddata.find('#' + table_id).DataTable().destroy(); 
        var data = ddata.html();  
        $('#idfortable').html(tempdata.html()); //replace to original state
        if (data) {
            
            var w = window.open('about:blank');
            w.document.open();
            w.document.write(data);
            
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image: Original image after restoring form table]